# Will it be possible to update jhipster entity without overwriting custom code

Tags: jhipster

According to the jhipster web site once we decide to update entity then the custom code will be overwriting.
Please suggest a way to update entity preserving the existing custom code.
https://www.jhipster.tech/creating-an-entity/

Comment: Some people use git branch merging to do so. In a way, it's like considering the generator as a team member who develops in his own branch and then you merge his changes with the rest of the team on the main branch.

Answer (score 2):

i think the safest way to solve this is :

1. Creating a new Jhipster project
2. Applying the updated JDL to it
3. Merging the custom code to newly created application

Of corse you have to use git

Answer (score 1):

You could always extend the generated entity (but not the endoints as it is not possible)

EDIT: endopits can be extended.